# Loops with graphics - bug in generating the graphics

Tags: java, loops, random, graphics, awt

I'm trying to make my code draw 10 rectangles, each one with a random position and size.

The problem is that, for some reason, it only draws one rectangle and never draws the other 9.

I'm using `Math.random`.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Punto1
        extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Estoy en el main");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Soy una ventana :D");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1280, 720);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocation(400, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(new Punto1());
    }

    public Punto1() {
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        /*if(x1 != 0 && y1 != 0 && x2 != 0 && y2 !=0){
         g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
         */
        rectangulo(g);
    }

    public void rectangulo(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int x = (int) Math.random() * 1120 + 75;
            int y = (int) Math.random() * 680 + 75;
            int width = (int) Math.random() * 960 + 50;
            int height = (int) Math.random() * 960 + 50;
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`(int)Math.random()` is truncating the value to an `int`, okay, but, `random` returns a value between `0` & `1`, meaning that, any value less then `1` will be, `0`, `0 x 1120` is `0` plus `75`, which is `75`, so you your code is drawing 10 rectangles in the same location

Two, possible solutions:

## One...

Cast the result of the calculation to `int` after it's performed:

```
int x = (int)(Math.random() * 1120 + 75)
```

This will ensure that the calculation is done against a `double` base value and the truncated to `int` after the result is calculated

## Two

Make use of the Graphics 2D API and use a `Rectangle2D` which supports double values...

```
double x = Math.random() * 1120 + 75;
double y = Math.random() * 680 + 75;
double width = Math.random() * 960 + 50;
double height = Math.random() * 960 + 50;
Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height);
((Graphics2D)g).draw(rect);
```

## Side note...

Also, unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise, you should call `setVisible` last - it will cause less issues

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Soy una ventana :D"); 
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
frame.setSize(1280,720);
frame.add(new Punto1());
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

## And finally (no, really ;))

Because of the way windows work an various operating systems, the panel is unlikely to be the same size as the window, in fact, in most cases, it's smaller.

In this case you should avoid relying on magic numbers and use known values

```
double x = Math.random() * getWidth() + 75;
double y = Math.random() * getHeight() + 75;
double width = Math.random() * (getWidth() / 2.0) + 50;
double height = Math.random() * (getHeight() / 2.0) + 50;
Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height);
((Graphics2D)g).draw(rect);
```

Comment: This answer should be used as a template here on SO. This is how an answer should look like - well formatted, well thought of and with followup hooks. Kodus!

Comment: Can't this concept be suggested here ?

Comment: @RannLifshitz You could make a suggestion on Meta - but I think it would be difficult as SO covers a wide range problem spaces. Maybe a "how to write a good answer" in the help section might help - but who reads the help ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really was the solution, i was not casting the values properly, and those suggestions are very nice aswell.